# The file "test.pdf" could not be opened on mac. [Ionic-iOS]

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to save the pdf in iOS using the Ionic Filesystem. I am using the below functions for writing the files.

```
Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: 'test',
      data: EStatementConstant.BinData,
      directory: Directory.Documents,
      encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
     });
```

Where EStatementConstant.BinData is my base64 data [validated] which I am getting directly from the API service.

The problem is that I am unable to open the file on a Mac. I didn't find any function to decode.

I am using capacitor v-3.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem?_gl=1*1i199tw*_ga*MTYzMjY4MzAzMi4xNjM0ODQxNDI4*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTY0ODgwMzI4NS40OS4wLjE2NDg4MDMyODUuMA..#type-401

Note:- **I am unable to save the pdf data without encoding in iOS. Also, I can not use the Cordova plugin.** I am struggling with this for the last few days. Please help.

[image: Problem image]

Comment: Cannot use Cordova plugin? any error prompted?

Comment: Hi @Raptor, Thanks for your prompt reply. Actually, there is a restriction using the Cordova plugin. My current code structure is fully based on capacitor plugins. I know that it is easily achievable via the Cordova plugin.